# How to use c# code found on this site and others

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not an expert in c# and .net I have been studying C# and .net for about 2 months. Im trying to build something that is probably a bit more advanced for my skill level. But I want to try anyways.

Most of the code, i need is found and has been written many times. In fact alot of it is found on this site! I hope one day soon to be able to start contributing.

My question is this:

When I find code like this:

```
public static SecurityIdentifier GetComputerSid()
{
    return new SecurityIdentifier(
        (byte[]) new DirectoryEntry(
            string.Format("WinNT://{0},Computer", Environment.MachineName))
            .Children
            .Cast<DirectoryEntry>()
            .First()
            .InvokeGet("objectSID"), 
         0)
        .AccountDomainSid;
}
```

Which suppose to get the SID, how do I make it function. I have my windows form with a button, I know( THINK) this is a class. Do I put it in a separate class file than call it to my main form1 file? If so does anyone have an example?

Do I step out of the button class and put the above code in there? If so, how do I extract the results? I have tried below and a BUNCH of other things.

```
Messagebox.Show(SecurityIdentifier.ToString())
```

I have been running into this problem when I try to use ANY code "Snippet" I find. How do I incorporate this code. I know most will say learn more than you will know. But I really want to build something and I do not have another year to practice before I do. And I think by finding code that I can use in fun projects, and incorporating them, will help me learn and keep me interested.

Comment: Um... You don't need to "make it a function". The code snippet you posted *is* a function already. You call it by using the *function name*, which is `GetComputerSID`, and it returns a `SecurityIdentifier`. It might help if you found a C# tutorial in order to learn the language basics.

Comment: It depends entirely on the snippet, and you haven't clarified what, in general, is going wrong with snippets you attempt to use. Incidentally, cargo-cult programming (borrowing code without understanding more than the most superficial idea of what it's supposed to do) is ***strongly*** counter-indicated: it leads to bugs, terrible system architecture, and slow development. Programming is not something you can really take shortcuts on without either paying the price yourself, or making others pay it for you.

Comment: I meant make it function. As in return the results, it suppose to get. While I do appreciate your response. And I KNEW someone would respond with learn the basics..I have done so  and iam struggling, which is the reason why im trying this way of learning. And it has been working. Unfortunately you do not agree with my approach which is your opinion. And you are entitled to that. Thanks.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I plan on hiring a tutor.

Comment: Nathan is right. 2 months is more than enough time to learn how to program. The reason you are not making progress is specifically because your technique is flawed; you are trying to learn French by asking people “if someone makes the sound ‘kell oor eht ill’ what sound do I make?” That is not how to learn anything. You have got to get a book or follow a tutorial. Do every exercise. Do not continue until you understand each exercise. If you don't understand an exercise, post it here and tell us what you think the exercise should do.

Comment: @DourHighArch I actually did every tutorial in this playlist https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0EE421AE8BCEBA4A and I understood it all, than I took a break for 2.5 months and forgot alot. Now im trying to pick it back up and make money at the same time. Even than when i was learning. I was writing simple programs of my own. But I was having a hard time reading and understanding other peoples code.

Comment: @DourHighArch i do agree with you somewhat. I was quite proficient a couple months back. But I forgot alot. Now something has fell in my lap, and i want to take advantage of it. Im also looking for a tutor. If you are for hire please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is tagged as with c# and .net, I'm assuming that you're using Visual Studio.

When you create a button in your Windows Forms application, double-clicking the button creates a METHOD for you in the code-behind file. That file is a CLASS file and can contain many different methods. The method that double-clicking the button creates should look something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}
```

The snippet that you want to use above is a stand-alone method, so, you can just add it to your class file. It should be inside of the class, but outside of any other methods, such as your button-click method that you created by double-clicking the button.

Inside of your button click method, you can call the snippet method and process any results returned from it. It should look something like the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SecurityIdentifier mySID = GetComputerSid();
    Messagebox.Show(mySID.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you John Hodge for answering my question! I really appreciate it! If you do any tutoring please let me know. Im looking to hire one.

Comment: Just tried it, and it worked perfectly! You just helped me understand ALOT more. Sometimes that is all you need. For things to start clicking in your head..( mine anyways) everyone learns differently. I want to be able to mess with other peoples code. And change it around and learn from it.